# Sliding not working in HTML5 web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have web page in which i want to slide the images from right to left it works fine on jsFiddle but when i edit that code in my web page it does not slide i don't know what is the problem.
Below is the online code which works fine but when i add this in my code it does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/WM5tA/7/

Comment: Could you post the URL of your web page?

Comment: I am just checking locally right now i have not uploaded to server

Comment: @SauloSilva may i show the HTML code of web page

Comment: you could either have the HTML in the description of your question or use a site like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My number one suggestion would be checking that your jquery file is included in your code, because jsFiddle does it for you.

Comment: i have included jquerry files 1.7 and in jsfiddle also it takes jquerry.ui i have alos included

Comment: may this is onLoad event i am calling this onLoad with anohtet function like <body onload="show();thisFunction()"; like this